# PDF in Latex Visibility of Header

Tags: header-footer, pdfpages

Can anybody help me with the following: I want to insert a PDF page into my Latex-file, however after I accomplish that, the header is not shown on that page that I have integrated. Is there any possibility to make the header visible? I used the package pdfpages.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, pgfplots, tikz, booktabs, tabularx, float, pgfplotstable, fancyhdr, subfigure, pdfpages}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[left=40mm, top=30mm, right=20mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=12.5mm, headheight=3mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\makebox[0pt][r]{Here is my header}
       \hspace*{1.66667em}
       \thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\setstretch{1.3}
\begin{document}
Text
\includepdf[pages={1}]{name_of_integrated_file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 2.2 of the »[pdfpages](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages)« manual introduces the `pagecommand` option for the `\includepdf` command. Hence you should try something like this.

```
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}]{name-of-integrated-file.pdf}
```